# how to set margin between TableRow android

Tags: android

I found a lot of solutions about TableRow margin, but when I tried the rows dont margin at all.

This is my code:

```
        TableLayout table = (TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.myTableLayout);

        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            TableRow tr = new TableRow(this);
            LayoutParams layoutParams = new LayoutParams(
                    LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
            int leftMargin=110;
            int topMargin=100;
            int rightMargin=100;
            int bottomMargin=100;
            layoutParams.setMargins(leftMargin, topMargin, rightMargin, bottomMargin);
            tr.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
            tr.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.shelf_bar);

            table.addView(tr, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
                    LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                    LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
        }
```

This is my expected result :

[image]

Please anyone point my mistake out. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

This is working:

```
TableRow tr = new TableRow(...);
TableLayout.LayoutParams lp = 
new TableLayout.LayoutParams(TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                             TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

lp.setMargins(10,10,10,10);             
tr.setLayoutParams(lp);

------

// the key is here!
yourTableLayoutInstance.addView(tr, lp);
```

You need to add your TableRow to TableLayout passing the layout parameters again!

Answer (score 0):

use this may

```
TableRow tr = new TableRow(this);  
TableLayout.LayoutParams tableRowParams=
  new TableLayout.LayoutParams
  (TableLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,TableLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);

        int leftMargin=10;
        int topMargin=2;
        int rightMargin=10;
        int bottomMargin=2;

tableRowParams.setMargins(leftMargin, topMargin, rightMargin, bottomMargin);

tr.setLayoutParams(tableRowParams);
```

Comment: My code currently is very small, in XML file only a simple table, and the code in my question is everything with java code

Comment: sorry ... I mean can you set margin to 10 2 10 2 instead of 110 100 100 100........

Comment: It still doesn't move at all, that really drives me insane

Comment: can you do one more thing ?try with out this line tr.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.shelf_bar);